# Getting data after real-time update

Tags: php, facebook, real-time

I have an application which has access to the user's feeds. 
I have setup realtime update for the application per this tutorial:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Essentially when a user posts an action to their feed, I successfully receive the information from Facebook to my call back link. The information looks like this:

```
{"object":"user","entry":[{"uid":"629498222","id":"629498222","time":1361371026,"changed_fields":["feed"]}]}
```

My troubles start there. Every tutorial that I have read on realtime updates finishes exactly at the point, without actually explaining how to get to the real data of the update.

So I am trying all sorts of things, in particular the following piece of code, to get the feed of the user so that I get access to the latest post. This is in my callback php file:

```
 $app_token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
               .$app_id.'&client_secret='.$app_secret
               .'&grant_type=client_credentials';
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $app_token_url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $res = curl_exec($ch);
 parse_str($res, $token);

 if (isset($token['access_token'])) {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/629498222/feed'
                              .'?access_token='
                              .$token['access_token']);
   $res = curl_exec($ch);
   if ($res && $res != 'null') {
     print_r($res);
   }
}
```

The result is not as expected. I get the posts for that user but only if they are public. I do not get all posts of that user, even though the application has access to the user stream. Any idea why?

Any help is greatly appreciated. I really need a way to finish the Realtime update by fetching the actual data from the user that posted the update.

Comment: Don't you have Extended User Access Token?

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of the real time service is to let applications know when the data they are caching is stale and should be refreshed.  It's not designed to be a "content subscription" service.

So when you get a notification, it's expected that you would then make a separate call for the updated information (for example, when the user logs in the next time).  Specifically for reading from the user's stream, it may be the case that read_stream permission is not granted to app tokens, although I can't find any definitive documentation to confirm that.  The closest I found is the "Other Capabilities of an App Access Token" on the bottom of this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/